# Laravel5.1 Testing JSON APIs ,Array or Object Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

My Test Code

```
public function test_Query()
{
    $this->post('/Controller/User_Controller/query', ['id' => $this::$id])
        ->seeJson([
            'data'   => [ 0 =>['username' =>  $this::$id.'_update']],
        ]);
}
```

But printf error

```
1) User_Test::test_Query
Unable to find JSON fragment ["data":[{"username":"1137598_update"}]] within [{"current_page":1,"data":[{"updated_at":"2015-10-29 18:57:13","username":"1137598_update"}]}].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I guess the match should not be a problem arrays and objects ? Or that I need all the attributes of data are included

Comment: Your data has to include `updated_at` attribute.

Comment: But I do not match the updated_at , only requires data in the same username and I ask to

Comment: Unfortunately seeJson works like this. It tries to match full attribute. Try to search for only `['username' =>  $this::$id.'_update']`

Comment: ok~thanks,I think that they should improve the
,Because seeJsonEquals able to verify all the attributes